# web audio api visualizer is not working in safari, music is playing though

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, audio, visualizer

visualizer is not appearing in safari only. The following code works fine in other browsers. 
  window.AudioContext=window.AudioContext||window.webkitAudioContext||window.mozAudioContext;

```
function player(){
context=new AudioContext();
analyser=context.createAnalyser();
canvas=document.getElementById('myCanvas');
ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');
var winWidth=$(window).outerWidth(true);
var cal=winWidth*62/100;
var canvasWidth=Math.round(cal);
if(winWidth>992){
    bars=150;
    ctx.canvas.width=canvasWidth;
}else{
    bars=100;
    ctx.canvas.width=winWidth-40;
}
ctx.fillRect(20,20,100,100);
gradient=ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,0,350);
gradient.addColorStop(1,'#000000');
gradient.addColorStop(0.5,'#F40606');
gradient.addColorStop(0,'#186F00');
source=context.createMediaElementSource(audio);
source.connect(analyser);
analyser.connect(context.destination);
x=0;
y=210;
w=canvas.width;
frameLooper();
```

}//player

```
function frameLooper(){
window.requestAnimationFrame(frameLooper);
fbc_array=new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
analyser.getByteFrequencyData(fbc_array);
ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
var logo=new Image();
logo.src="/images/logo3.png";
for(var yo=0;yo<bars;yo++){
    bar_x2=yo*8;
    bar_width=4;
    bar_height2=-(fbc_array[yo]/2);
    ctx.fillStyle=gradient;
    ctx.fillRect(bar_x2,canvas.height,bar_width,bar_height2);
}

ctx.drawImage(logo,x,y,w,bar_height2*2);
```

}//frameLooper

```
var audio,playbtn,mutebtn,seek_bar,volumeslider;
function initAudioPlayer(){
audio=new Audio();
audio.src="/audio/mu.mp3";
audio.loop=true;
player();
audio.play();

audio.volume=0.1;
setTimeout(function(){audio.volume=0.2;},500);
setTimeout(function(){audio.volume=0.3;},500);
setTimeout(function(){audio.volume=0.4;},2000);
setTimeout(function(){audio.volume=0.5;},3000);
setTimeout(function(){audio.volume=0.6;},4000);
setTimeout(function(){audio.volume=0.7;},5000);
setTimeout(function(){audio.volume=0.8;},6000);
setTimeout(function(){audio.volume=0.9;},7000);
setTimeout(function(){audio.volume=1.0;},8000);

if(audio.paused){
$('#logo').fadeIn(500);
$('#canvasWrap').hide();
$('#playPause').removeClass('icon-pause');
$('#playPause').addClass('icon-play');
}else{
$('#logo').hide();
$('#canvasWrap').fadeIn(500);
$('#playPause').removeClass('icon-play');
$('#playPause').addClass('icon-pause'); 
}

playbtn=document.getElementById('playPause');
playbtn.addEventListener("click",playPause);

function playPause(){
if(audio.paused){
    $('#logo').hide();
    $('#canvasWrap').fadeIn(500);
    $('#playPause').removeClass('icon-play');
    $('#playPause').addClass('icon-pause');
    // $('#trackInfo').fadeIn(500);
    audio.play();       
}else{
    $('#canvasWrap').hide();
    $('#logo').fadeIn(500);
    $('#playPause').removeClass('icon-pause');
    $('#playPause').addClass('icon-play');
    // $('#trackInfo').fadeOut(500);
    audio.pause();    
}   
}//playPause

window.addEventListener("load",initAudioPlayer,true);
```